# Roles class asp.net mvc?

Tags: roles, asp.net-roles

where the Roles class store the roles that he creates, what is the type of role providers that support this class?

is it SqlRoleProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx) I think you will find the answer to your question.

read this section in the article:

***Using SqlRoleProvider***

> *If you want to store roles in SQL Server, you
>   use the SqlRoleProvider. By default, roles are stored in a database
>   named Aspnetdb in a SQL Express database instance in the \app_data
>   folder beneath your application's virtual directory root folder. You
>   can also configure the SqlRoleProvider to use a local or remote
>   instance of SQL Server.*